# The WSDL document is invalid for following Error creating model from wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, middleware

I'am trying to generate a wsdl proxy in jdev, but I get this error: 
"The WSDL document is invalid for following
Error creating model from wsdl
file:/D:BitbucketAveaWorkspace/Esb/EsbModel/src/etiya/mts/model/ws/offer/retrieveoffer/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS.wsdl
Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.(Related to above error) This is the other declaration."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEjdo.png)

I've tried almost all the solutions I've done in Google, but it did not. Is there anyone that can help me or Anyone suggest for this question. Thanks.

Wsdl:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com.tr/om/wsdl/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.abc.com.tr/om/wsdl/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS" xmlns:ns="http://www.abc.com.tr/om/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS" xmlns:fault="http://www.abc.com.tr/Fault">
      <wsdl:documentation>This service provides operations to retrieve prepaid or postpaid product
            details.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com.tr/om/EbsProductOfferOperations" elementFormDefault="qualified">
          <xs:import namespace="http://www.abc.com.tr/om/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS" schemaLocation="../aveaXsd/EBS_PRODUCT_OFFER_OPERATIONS.xsd"/>
          <xs:import namespace="http://www.abc.com.tr/Fault" schemaLocation="../aveaXsd/Fault.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePromotionOfferRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePromotionOfferReq"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="RetrievePromotionOfferResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:RetrievePromotionOfferResp"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="CustomerProductAssignmentRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:CustomerProductAssignmentRequest"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="CustomerProductAssignmentResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="ns:CustomerProductAssignmentResponse"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" element="fault:ExceptionSchema"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="EbsProductOfferOperationsPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidCommitmentOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for postpaid commitment (Taahhüt)</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePostpaidCommitmentOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidFreeUnitOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for postpaid freeunit</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePostpaidFreeUnitOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidServiceOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for a postpaid service.</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePostpaidServiceOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidTariffOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for a postpaid tariff.</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePostpaidTariffOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidBonusOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for a prepaid bonus.</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePrepaidBonusOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidServiceOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for a prepaid service product.</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePrepaidServiceOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidTariffOffer">
          <wsdl:documentation>This method can be used to return details for a prepaid tariff product.</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePrepaidTariffOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePromotionOffer">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:RetrievePromotionOfferRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:RetrievePromotionOfferResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="customerProductAssignment">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:CustomerProductAssignmentRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:CustomerProductAssignmentResponse"/>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="EbsProductOfferOperationsBinding" type="tns:EbsProductOfferOperationsPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidCommitmentOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePostpaidCommitmentOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidFreeUnitOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePostpaidFreeUnitOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidServiceOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePostpaidServiceOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePostpaidTariffOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePostpaidTariffOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidBonusOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePrepaidBonusOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidServiceOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePrepaidServiceOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePrepaidTariffOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePrepaidTariffOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrievePromotionOffer">
          <soap:operation soapAction="retrievePromotionOffer"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="customerProductAssignment">
          <soap:operation soapAction="customerProductAssignment"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
          <wsdl:fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="EbsProductOfferOperations">
        <wsdl:port name="EbsProductOfferOperationsPortType" binding="tns:EbsProductOfferOperationsBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:1233/MTSEsb-AveaEsbModel-context-root/EbsProductOfferOperationsPortTypeImplService/EbsProductOfferOperations/EbsProductOfferOperations?wsdl"/>
            </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: First try to check if the WSDL file you have is valid using the tool [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: Wsdl is valid in SoapUI tools.

Comment: Using SoapUI you can generate Java web-services client code. Here is some useful links [SOAP Code Generation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html)    and [Generating Client JAVA code for WSDL using SOAP UI](https://dzone.com/articles/generating-client-java-code)

Comment: when I generate wsdl in jdev, I got an error. I check the namespaces in the wsdl ,but  everything is true.  @Salman  I generated wsdl in Soap successfully, I is not require for me.